# Converting localized string date representation to UTC in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

How do I convert the following localized datetime string to UTC datetime. The string has date, time and timezone mentioned in it e.g. `May 15,2015, 04.24AM IST`, here IST is Indian Standard Time. It can be any time zone.
I tried using pytz but couldn't make it work.

Comment: How do you know its Indian Standard Time, and not [Irish Summer Time, Israeli Standard Time or Iran Standard Time](http://www.worldtimezone.com/wtz-names/wtz-ist.html)? Using abbreviated timezones makes converting times difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that it's quite difficult to parse a string with an abbreviated timezone information. But, if you know your timezone, then you can look up it's name recognized by `pytz`. You can even list all timezone names with `pytz.all_timezones`.

In your case it is 'Asia/Calcutta' and this should work to convert it to UTC. Just strip the timezone information from the string and add it later:

```
import pytz
import datetime

# String without timezone info
str = "May 15, 2015, 04.24AM"
# Parse it to naive time
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%b %d, %Y, %I.%M%p")
# Localize it as Asia/Calcutta
dt_localized = pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta').localize(dt)
# Convert it to UTC
dt_utc = dt_localized.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
```

And we get:

```
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 4, 24)

>>> dt_localized
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 4, 24, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>)

>>> dt_utc
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 14, 22, 54, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's strip your date string of the IST timezone and then assign it the Asia/Calcutta timezone.

```
import pytz

dt_str = "May 15, 2015, 04.24AM IST"
dt_str_naive = dt_str[:-4]

new_dt = (pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
          .localize(dt.datetime.strptime(dt_str_naive, "%b %d, %Y, %I.%M%p")))
```

Now that it is timezone aware, you can assign it to the UTC timezone:

```
>>> new_dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 14, 22, 54, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```